# Images in Mailchimp email very large in Gmail

Tags: email, gmail, mailchimp

I have a MailChimp template I am working on for a client. In Gmail only, I get some images that are much larger than the stated dimensions in the template. In this example, the image is shown in Gmail at 600px x 120px but the `<td>` is:

```
<td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;vertical-align:top" height="4px" width="600px">
                                <img src="http://www.marketingscience.co/boa/hero-header.png" style="display:block;border:0;min-height:4px;width:600px;background-color:#696969;color:white;font-size:18px;line-height:100%;outline:none;text-decoration:none">
                              </td>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your inline css is setting the width to 600px.  Is gmail displaying it wider than 600px?

Comment: Actually the width is fine. The height of the image is 4px in the code but shows in gmail as 120px tall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting image dimesions in plain html, like this:

```
<img src="image.png" width="100px" height="300px" />
```

Also, you have no height set in 'style' attribute, so adding it may solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Add a style element in your email template and set some default styles for all images in your email, like this:

```
 <style>
   img {
     display:block;
     height:auto;
     line-height:100%;
   }
 </style>
```

MailChimp will add these styles inline to every `<img>` element before it sends the email.

Then, when possible, add the `height` and `width` attributes to each image as Alex Ponomarev suggested.